# grid view for any table with add and edit and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

i search for gridview user control opensource that allow me to set tabename then its how tabe data and allow adding new row edit delete row , i searched online and didn't find any .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing Silverlight you can have a free gridview from DevExpress, http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/silverlight/grid/

For WinForms there is SourceGrid in CodePlex, http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/

For ASP.NET, try webgrid, http://www.webgrid.com/

There's also this SO post with a pretty good list of free controls (grids included):  [Best Free Controls for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)

Answer (score 1):

U can use Obout Grid Controls.............
http://obout.com/inc/download.aspx..these are the best controls i have seen u can do any changes u want, the download come with tutorials two....

u can check this link before u download...
http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_default_values_for_add.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not a .net version but you can use the same javascript from this script http://www.amitpatil.me/add-edit-delete-rows-dynamically-using-jquery-php/